# Permissions Bluetooth Android Maui

Tags: bluetooth, android-permissions, maui, maui-android

Is there a possibility to allow Bluetooth for Android when starting the app in Maui. Not with a button. Thank you .

I made an app with a button to authorize Bluetooth .

Comment: just execute the code from the button in one of the App lifecycle events

Answer (score 0):

Just as Jason said, you can put your code about request the bluetooth permission in some lifecycle events.

Such as in the mainpage's onappearing method:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    // the code about request permission
    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

Or in the /Platfrom/Android/MainActivity.cs:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(saveInstanceState)
    //the code about request permission
}
```